# pyqt5 progressdialog showing on wrong screen

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm running a Qt5 application with a main application window and trying to show a progress dialog window. I have a multi screen system, when starting the application the main window is displayed on the screen where it has been executed which is fine, but the progress dialog when executed is shown on a different screen!?

Here is a simple example code that causes the problem for me

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self._show_progress()

    def _show_progress(self):
        self._progress = QProgressDialog('msg', None, 0, 0, self)
        self._progress.setWindowTitle('Please wait...')
        self._progress.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)
        self._progress.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    cb_app = Example()
    cb_app.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Can I somehow specify where the the dialog should be shown (ideally on top of the main window)?

I'm using Linux Mint 18.2, window manager `X-Cinnamon` and PyQt version 5.5.1

Comment: did you try `self._progress.setGeometry(...)` with coordinates of your main window?

Comment: A modal window should always be positioned on top of its parent window. What specific version of qt5 are you using, and on what platform? If you are on linux, what window manager are you using?

Comment: @ekhumoro Updated the requested information

Comment: Does this happen with all dialogs, or just QProgressDialog?